# Django - Custom permissions for function based views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

how can I write custom permissions for a function based view? I am using the REST framework, and I have written a ciphertext encryption/decryption API. I have one function based view for each key (`key-detail`) which I would like to only make available to the owner of that key. I know that when using class based views, it is enough to define `permission_classes`, but how do I do this for function based views? I have tried using the `@permission_classes` decorator, but it is not working for my custom permission, which is written as so:

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to access it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like it's a known issue, `has_object_permission` is not supported when using function based views, it's reported [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1697).

If you would like to call `has_permission`, you should be able to do so using the `permission_classes` decorator as shown in the [documentation](http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/permissions)

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def example_view(request, format=None):
    content = {
        'status': 'request was permitted'
    }
    return Response(content)
```

Comment: But it is a view function, there is no such thing as `self` so I cannot call `self.check_object_permissions(request, obj)`.

Comment: The api_view decorator now expects a list of strings, instead of a string. 
So, using the above method may result in AssertionError, if so, try using @api_view(['GET']), instead of @api_view('GET').

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the [@Forge answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520893/7857541) but If **you still want to accomplish such things. You can follow this-**

```
@api_view(['ANY_METHOD'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def model_delete_view(request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    if not obj.exists():
        return Response(
            {'message': 'MyModel not found'},
            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        )
    obj = obj.filter(user=request.user)
    if not obj.exists():
        return Response(
            {'message': 'You are not authorizated'},
            status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        )
    obj.delete()
    return Response({'message': 'MyModel deleted'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to add these words before def function_name ():

```
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
def func_name (request):
   # Enter your code here.
```

**Take careful in square brackets**